# Is IntelliJ better alternative to Visual Studio for C++ Projects?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, intellij-idea

I'm a first year Computer Science student, I have to submit projects in my semester; my professor recommended Visual Studio but VS doesn't run in my Windows 10 laptop. I've made up my mind not to use VS, is IntelliJ a good alternative for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think Intellj is a great alternative, it is a very powerful and awesome IDE.

As a first year computer science I think it would be better to use Intellj since it supports many other languages and it will be useful for you to learn how to get around with using it early on.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally do everything on the VSCode.It is also a good IDE for C++ because it gives access to a lot of Plugins and easy Feature.IntelliJ is also a good IDE platform but it more focused on the Java and also it consumes a lot of Memory.According to me you should go for VScode rather than IntelliJ at this Stage.Later you can decide what to use according to your ease and need.Hope you get it.